# How to get index of object in observablecollection passed as parameter

Tags: c#, object, collections, parameters, indexing

so here it is:

```
Bowls = new ObservableCollection<Bowl>();

SowCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => SowGame(param));

private void SowGame(Object param)
{
Int32 index = Convert.ToInt32(param);

Bowls[index] = ...
}
```

So i pass "param" to SowGame by pressing a button Command="{Binding SowCommand}"

param is now an object of Bowl type

in SowGame i want to do something with this Bowl object and i know a certain object from a collection can be reached by using Bowls[index of object]. But converting the object to int as above doesn't seem to work.

How can i get the index of the passed object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Here's what caused the problem:

```
SowCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => SowGame(param));
```

To be able to get the index of the pressed button (which is bound to the above command) you need two things:

First you need to implement a function which somehow computes the index of an element in a collection. For example in my case:

```
public Int32 Number { get {

            if (Y == 0)
            {
                return _Size - 1 - X;
            }
            else
            {
                return _Size + X;
            }

        } }
```

Of course the method of getting the index depends on the problem. The above code is a part of the implementation of my Bowl type.

After this you have to add

```
Command Parameter="{Binding Number}"
```

to your *.xaml* and the code in the question should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use IndexOf method of your ObservableCollection:

```
int index = Bowls.IndexOf((Bowl)param);
```

Comment: it returns -1. that means indexof can't find param in bowls, but it's in there

Comment: is this bound to a datagrid? can you just pass the selected index as the param?

Comment: @GáborBirkás: Are you sure that param _object_ is in the collection and not an object that just look to be same (i.e. has same values)?

Comment: @Dev: yes, i added each bowl to the bowls collection

Comment: @GáborBirkás: ok, this is slightly out of the context, but if you have your Bowl object in the param variable, why do you want to get its index and then use that index to extract exactly same object from the Bowls collection?

Comment: @Dev: to be able to do something with the button. I have a button, there's a command bound to it, after the button is pushed i need to know which one was that and since i don't want to bind different commands to every button in the grid i have to get the index of the pressed button inside the command.

Comment: @GáborBirkás: Also, does the Bowl class override Equals method or implement IEquatable interface (or something like that)?